# How to prevent GMail from converting text to URL?

Tags: php, hyperlink, gmail

I have a small issue with GMail. My company has a ".fr" part in its name, and when we send newletters, GMail shows it as an internet adress and autmatically adds a link to it.

That's not what I want.

I found [a very good solution here](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/12_things_you_must_know_when_developing_for_gmail_and_gmail_mobile_apps#gmail_tip9), and it works like a charm when I manually edit the HTML file. The magic is to add a character GMail does not know, like `&#173;`, so that is does not transform the text into a link.

The problem is when I try to automate this replacement :

```
$body = str_replace('my company.fr', "my company&#173;.fr", $body);
```

PHP does not seem to see this `&#173;` character, and for the little story, neither does Google...

Do you know of a way to achieve my goal, that is not having a link on my company name ?

I could do the second option in the above mentioned article, but that, to my opinion, would be my last option.

Thanks for your replies !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can need ' not " for this special char

```
    $body = "my company.fr"
    $body = str_replace('my company.fr', 'my company&#173;.fr', $body);
    //result is my company&#173;.fr
```

And using html_entity_decode for back

```
    $st  = "my company&#173;.fr"
    $st  = html_entity_decode($st);
    //result is my company.fr
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Why didn't I think of a so simple solution ? :) I used htmlentities() instead of html_entity_decode(), because I needed to display the result. Thanx for pointing me to the solution !!
Here is the code I am using :

    $invisible = htmlentities('&#173;', ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
    $body = str_replace('my company.fr', 'my company' . $invisible . '.fr', $body);

Comment: Sorry, i have new solutions for you, i don't read deep your question. 
$body = str_replace('my company.fr', 'my company&#173;.fr', $body);
using ' not " in replace for special character.